# trying to find initial condition for an integral depending a variable

Tags: real-analysis

Let

$$ F( \alpha) = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\alpha^2 - \sin^2 x) \mathrm{d}x \; \; \; \; \; \; \alpha>1 $$

let $G(\alpha,x) = \ln(\alpha^2 - \sin^2 x)$ I know $F'( \alpha) = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 \alpha }{\alpha^2 - \sin^2 x } dx$

Using the substitution $u = \tan x$, I was able to solve this integral and I obtained

$$ F'(\alpha) = \frac{ \pi }{\sqrt{ \alpha^2 - 1 } } \implies F(\alpha) = \pi \ln \left(\alpha + \sqrt{ \alpha^2 - 1 } \right)+C$$

However, I need to find the value of $C$. How can I do that? I mean, I know I need to find some $b$ constant so that $F(b) = constant$ in the original $F$ from the first equation above. But, I unable to find such $b$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $F(1)$ is classic integral (calculated many times on this site) which fixes your constant

Comment: but notice $F(1)$ is not defined. But, this would only work if $\lim_{\alpha \to 1^+ } F(\alpha) = F(1)$ which I dont see how to prove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the constant by looking at the dependence for $\alpha \to \infty$. Taylor expansion for small $\sin x \ll \alpha$ leads to the result 
$$F(\alpha)= \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\alpha^2 -\sin^2 x)  =\frac{\pi}{2} \ln \alpha^2  +O(\alpha^{-2})= \pi \ln \alpha + O(\alpha^{-2}).$$

From your expression, we obtain
$$F(\alpha) = \pi \ln(2 \alpha) +C +o(1)= \pi \ln \alpha + \pi \ln 2 +C +o(1)$$
for the same limit ($\alpha \to \infty$). This sets the constant to $$C= -\pi \ln2.$$

Comment: Silly downvote on this answer. (+1) back.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right) = \frac{2n}{2^n},\tag{1} $$
by switching to logarithms, then Riemann sums, we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(x)\,dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2\tag{2} $$
hence
$$ \color{red}{C}=\lim_{\alpha\to 1^+}F(\alpha) = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\cos(x)\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(x)\,dx = \color{red}{-\pi\log(2)}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: I dont understand (2). When I write the definition of integral as riemman sum, I dont get a product as in (1), thus we can't use (1). can you explain a little bit more (2) ?

Comment: @Jibarito: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\log\frac{2n}{2^n}=-\pi\log 2.$$